# What happens when i install bundle at runtime in OSGi bundle context

Tags: osgi, equinox

At run time i am installing a bundle ,that bundle's Bundle-ActivationPolicy is eager.what will be the bundle  state resolve or install or active?. exactly at what state bundle will be after installation at run time?
 i am installing using bundleContext.installBundle(URL);

Answer (score 1):

When you install a bundle it first enters the **INSTALLED** state.

The lifecycle of an OSGi bundle is found in section 4.4 of the [OSGi R6 Core Specification](https://www.osgi.org/developer/downloads/release-6/). Refer in particular to Figure 4.4 on page 107 which shows the state transition diagram.

You almost certainly don't need to use `Bundle-ActivationPolicy` eager. It does not do what you think it does, and what it actually does is hardly ever useful. I strongly recommend you ignore it.

Comment: will bundle starts after installation? or do we need to start?

Comment: No it will not start, which is why I gave the answer I gave. If you want to start it, call `Bundle.start`.

Comment: i have A, B, C bundles  m installing at run time A and C depends on B so i want start B first for that i want give start levels at run time is that possible?

Comment: Why do you think these bundles need to be started in a specific order?

Comment: if i start A before B, giving an error Service not available exception that service implemented in B.so i want start B first

Comment: That's the wrong approach. You should be able to start bundles in any order. See http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Avoid_Start_Order_Dependencies

Comment: i am running my plugins in eclipse i want put a config.ini where to write that file

Comment: This sounds like a new question.

Comment: As Bundle A depending on B, what happens when I try to start bundle A before B? Will it throw BundleException saying unresolved bundle B?

Comment: No it will not. Starting and resolving are separate phases; OSGi is able to resolve a set of interdependent bundles in one operation. You really don't need to worry about resolution... just start the bundles, and OSGi will figure out which bundles need to be resolved.